# Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [resources:1.1.6]: Cannot get property 'pluginPath'

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, grails-plugin

Using grails 1.3.7 i have no problem compiling and running my project from my STS.
The error listed below occurs after packaging the WAR and trying to deply it from apache tomcat. This problem has not occured before and i have had success deploying it to apache tomcat in the same fashion before. (Using apache-tomcat-7.0.26).

In regards to the error:
at BootstrapResources.run(BootstrapResources.groovy:23) row 23 points to:

def twitterbootstrapPlugin = applicationContext.pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin('twitter-bootstrap')

**row 23** --> twitterbootstrapPluginDir = applicationContext.getResource(twitterbootstrapPlugin.pluginPath).file

```
ERROR [pool-2-thread-1] (DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:818) - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [resources:1.1.6]: Cannot get property 'pluginPath' on null object java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'pluginPath' on null object
    at BootstrapResources.run(BootstrapResources.groovy:23)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory$_getModuleDeclarations_closure2.doCall(ModuleDeclarationsFactory.groovy:43)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory.getModuleDeclarations(ModuleDeclarationsFactory.groovy:38)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory.getModuleDeclarations(ModuleDeclarationsFactory.groovy)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.module.ModuleDeclarationsFactory$getModuleDeclarations.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.loadModules(ResourceProcessor.groovy:720)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.this$2$loadModules(ResourceProcessor.groovy)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$this$2$loadModules.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.reloadAll(ResourceProcessor.groovy:1056)
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$reloadAll.call(Unknown Source)
    at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The latest additions to the project has been spring-security-core, but i cant see how this could be an issue.

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not a generic solution for this problem, but for my project this was an issue of my maven packaging not including all the needed plugins for successful deployment.

For some reason having defined my plugins within my BuildConfig.groovy file as follows:

```
plugins{
    build ':whateverplugin:0.1'
    compile ':whateverplugin:0.1'
    runtime ':whateverplugin:0.1'
    test ':whateverplugin:0.1'
}
```

The plugins were not including in the war packaging when packaging my project issuing the command:
mvn package -Dmaven.skip.test=true